# How to Create a Dataframe With A List of Uneven Lists

Tags: r, json, api

I am working with some API data that outputs in a JSON file. The main problem with this data is that using the function `fromJSON`, I get a "list of lists" that looks like this (`head` applied):

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`agency_code`
[1] 7

[[1]]$applicant_income_000s
[1] 56

[[1]]$action_taken
[1] 1

[[1]]$as_of_year
[1] 2015


[[2]]
[[2]]$`agency_code`
[1] 9

[[2]]$applicant_income_000s
[1] 27

[[2]]$action_taken
[1] 1

[[2]]$as_of_year
[1] 2015


[[3]]
[[3]]$`agency_code`
[1] 9

[[3]]$applicant_income_000s
[1] 90

[[3]]$action_taken
[1] 1

[[3]]$as_of_year
[1] 2015


[[4]]
[[4]]$`agency_code`
[1] 9

[[4]]$action_taken
[1] 1

[[4]]$as_of_year
[1] 2015
```

As you can see, `$applicant_income_000s` is missing in the 4th list element (and in many more).

I want to make a `dataframe` where the missing elements are coded. The problem I am running into is with `rbind`. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. `df <- as.data.frame(json.list.data)`
2. `df <- rbind.data.frame(json.list.data, deparse.level = 1)`
3. `df <- as.data.frame(rbind(json.list.data, deparse.level = 1)`

Ideally, the API query would have included fields for missing values, such as `applicant_income_000s = .`, but it does not. Instead, it omits the field, yielding uneven lists which are the root of my problem!

Does anyone have an idea for this problem? I really appreciate your time!

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample of my list data, from `dput(head())`:

```
list(list(agency_code = 7, applicant_income_000s = 56, action_taken = 1, 
as_of_year = 2015), list(agency_code = 9, applicant_income_000s = 27, 
action_taken = 1, as_of_year = 2015), list(agency_code = 9, 
applicant_income_000s = 90, action_taken = 1, as_of_year = 2015), 
list(agency_code = 9, action_taken = 1, as_of_year = 2015), 
list(agency_code = 5, applicant_income_000s = 212, action_taken = 1, 
    as_of_year = 2015), list(agency_code = 7, action_taken = 1, 
    as_of_year = 2015))
```

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows` is smarter about out-of-order and missing variables, so just `dplyr::bind_rows(your_list)` should work. `data.table::rbindlist(your_list, fill = TRUE)` will also work, though you may need to coerce the result back to a vanilla data.frame if you aren't otherwise using data.table.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!